# CSS Style override in Unix Shell

Tags: html, css, shell, unix, sendmail

I am trying to send email from Unix using a HTML code. For paragraph tag I am trying to override style but its not working

```
(
echo "From: $FROM"
echo "To: $TO"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<style>"
echo "table {border: 1px solid black; }"
echo "body { font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #FFFFFF; }"
echo "p { font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }"
echo "</style>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<p style="font-style: bold";>${BodyHeading}:</p>"   
echo "<p>Content of the email: </p>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
) | sendmail $TO
```

@Line 14 we are overriding style for paragraph tag. But when we get email we are not getting bold text for that p tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(
echo "From: $FROM"
echo "To: $TO"
echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html>"
echo "<style>"
echo "table {border: 1px solid black; }"
echo "body { font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; background-color: #FFFFFF; }"
echo "p { font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }"
echo "</style>"
echo "<body>"
echo "<p style='font-weight: bold;'>${BodyHeading}:</p>"   
echo "<p>Content of the email: </p>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
) | sendmail $TO
```

Replace Line 15 with `echo "<p style='font-weight: bold;'>${BodyHeading}:</p>"` and it should work. 
more over id you want to use double quotes(`"`) in echo statements, then you should escape them using `\` . E.g.

`echo "<p style=\"font-weight: bold;\">${BodyHeading}:</p>"`

Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 1):

Replace  `echo "<p style="font-style: bold";>${BodyHeading}:</p>"`  with echo `"<p style="font-weight: bold";>${BodyHeading}:</p>"`

Comment: I changed it to : echo "<p style="font-weight: bold";>${BodyHeading}:</p>" but not working

Comment: echo "p { font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }" is this working?

Comment: then there itself write font-weight: bold.